# If ‎$‎f$ ‎is a ‎concave function ‎then ‎$‎f$ ‎is ‎increasing‎

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

My question is how to prove the following assertion:

> If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a concave function such that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-f(x-1))=0$ then $f$ increasing.

I know that if ‎$‎‎f$ ‎is ‎differentiable ‎then the ‎mentioned ‎hypothesis ($f'$ is decreasing) and using M.V.T ‎imply ‎that firstly ‎‎$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'‎(x)=0$ also ‎‎$‎f'‎\geq0$ and $‎‎f$‎ ‎is ‎increasing. ‎but ‎here ‎we ‎do not ‎have ‎the differentiability.

‎Anyone ‎can ‎help ‎me. Thanks.‎

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Since $f$ is concave it follows that for any $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ the function
$$x\to R(x,x_0):=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$
is decreasing in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x_0\}$. Here it is a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_one_variable) for the convex function $-f$.

Now assume that $f$ is not increasing. Then there are $x_0,x_1$ such that $x_0<x_1$ and $f(x_1)<f(x_0)$. It follows that
$$0>R(x_1,x_0)\geq R(x_0+k+1,x_0)\geq R(x_0+k+1,x_0+k)$$
where $k$ is any positive integer such that $x_0+k>x_1$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: @ Robert Z, Would you explain more that what happens for $f$ And how limit condition helps?

Comment: @soodehMehboodi See my edit.

Comment: @ Robert Z, You mean that it made contradiction with be decreasing of $R(x)$ but I want to know that where  is $f(x)-f(x-1)\to0$ used?

Comment: One single step is missing and I did not use the limit of  $f(x)-f(x-1)=R(x-1,x)$ yet.

Comment: @ Robert Z, I think you proved the assertion "$f$ is increasing from a number on," but  it seems the limit condition makes it hold for all $x\in R$.

Comment: No. The proof is by contradiction. What is the limit of $R(x_0+k+1,x_0+k)$ as $k\to +\infty$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91126/discussion-between-soodehmehboodi-and-robert-z).